# Is this the right syntax for inheriting super class in Kotlin?

Tags: class, kotlin, inheritance

Is this the right syntax for inheriting superclass in Kotlin ? What I studied that subclass must have included parameters of their superclass. But here as you can see, Noodles and Vegetables class have no parameters. Why?

```
open class Item(val name: String, val price: Int)

class Noodles : Item("Noodles", 10)

class Vegetables : Item("Vegetables", 5) 

fun main() {
    val noodles = Noodles()
    val vegetables = Vegetables()
    println(noodles)
    println(vegetables)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is the right syntax.  And you *are* providing the necessary parameters!

Your `Item` class has a primary constructor which takes two parameters: `name` and `price`.  And, as you learned, since that's the *only* constructor, it means that whenever you construct an instance of `Item` or any subclass, you have to provide values for those two parameters.

But you're providing those values — `"Noodles"` and `10` in one case, and `"Vegetables"` and `5` in the other — directly at the point where you call the superclass constructor.

In practice, it's more common for the subclass to require them to be provided to *it* in the same way, and then passed up to the superclass, e.g.:

```
class Noodles(val name: String, val price: Int) : Item(name, price)
```

But there's nothing wrong with hard-coding them directly as you've done — and sometimes that's a good approach.  As long as `Item`'s `name` and `price` get set *somehow*, it should all work!

The [language documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/home.html) is, as usual, the main reference; it discusses all this [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html).

Comment: Got it!! Thank you for the helpful explanation.